# finite length object and direct sum in an abelian category

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

Let $C$ be an abelian category and let $X$ an object with finite length.

Then $X$ has a composition series

$$0=X_0<X_1< \cdots X_n=X$$
where $X_i/X_{i-1}$ is simple for $i=1, \dots, n$.

**Question** Is $X=X_0 \oplus X_1/X_0 \oplus \cdots \oplus X_n/X_{n-1}$?

Comment: In general a module can have a proper simple submodule that isn't a direct summand, right? Trying to think of an example...

Comment: What examples have you considered? The answer is no except in very exceptional cases!

Answer (score 3):

No. For example, $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$ has a composition series consisting of two copies of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, but it is not isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^2$. As in your previous question, this reflects the existence of interesting [Ext groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_functor) in general (even between simple objects).